# ¿Cómo hago para dejar esta instrucción completamente amarillo en adición y sustracción de imágenes con OpenCV y Python?

Tags: python, opencv, cv2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy usando la instrucción

```
Color = cv2.absdiff(mG, mB)
```

y quiero cambiarlo para dejarlo completamente amarillo sin combinar colores de RGB, o ¿existe una combinación que no sea mG, mB?

Comment: Lo importante: ¿qué es lo que buscás que esté en amarillo? Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Lo que busco es que se capture la placa colombiana color amarillo con letras negras, ya que mi código está detectando objetos azules y rojos. Se adjunta imágen del error